# Elementwise multiplication of several arrays in Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multiplication

Coding some Quantum Mechanics routines, I have discovered a curious behavior of Python's NumPy. When I use NumPy's multiply with more than two arrays, I get faulty results. In the code below, i have to write:

```
f = np.multiply(rowH,colH)
A[row][col]=np.sum(np.multiply(f,w))
```

which produces the correct result. However, my initial formulation was this:

```
A[row][col]=np.sum(np.multiply(rowH, colH, w))
```

which does not produce an error message, but the wrong result. Where is my fault in thinking that I could give three arrays to numpy's multiply routine?

Here is the full code:

```
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import Hermite, hermgauss
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dim = 3
x,w = hermgauss(dim)
A = np.zeros((dim, dim))
#build matrix
for row in range(0, dim):
    rowH = Hermite.basis(row)(x)
    for col in range(0, dim):
        colH = Hermite.basis(col)(x)
        #gaussian quadrature in vectorized form
        f = np.multiply(rowH,colH)
        A[row][col]=np.sum(np.multiply(f,w))
print(A)
```

**::NOTE::** this code only runs with **NumPy 1.7.0** and higher!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your fault is in not reading [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html):

> `numpy.multiply(x1, x2[, out])`

`multiply` takes exactly two input arrays.  The optional third argument is an output array which can be used to store the result.  (If it isn't provided, a new array is created and returned.)  When you passed three arrays, the third array was overwritten with the product of the first two.

Comment: ok, my bad :-). should I remove this post or do you think it's useful for others?

Comment: leave it. helped me :)

Comment: So, is there any option to multiply multiple arrays in a single call (in latest version) or do we have to chain the calls?

Answer (score 20):

For anyone stumbling upon this, the best way to apply an element-wise multiplication of n `np.ndarray` of shape `(d, )` is to first `np.vstack` them and apply `np.prod` on the first axis:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> arrays = [
...   np.array([1, 2, 3]),
...   np.array([5, 8, 2]),
...   np.array([9, 2, 0]),
... ]
>>>
>>> print(np.prod(np.vstack(arrays), axis=0))
[45 32  0]
```

Comment: This answer assume that input arrays are 1D. Taking `np.prod(np.array(arrays), axis=0))` works better for multi-dimensional input arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Simply as doing * to np.arrays

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([2,9,4])
b=np.array([3,4,5])
c=np.array([10,5,8])
d=a*b*c
print(d)
```

Produce:

```
[ 60 180 160]
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question because I was interested in knowing the fastest way to multiply several arrays together. I ended up writing a benchmark, and I'm surprised by what I found.

I tested 3 methods:

1. Using pure python syntax `a * b * c * d`
2. Using np.multiply.reduce
3. Using np.stack followed by np.prod(..., axis=0)

I tested these methods with multiple numbers of arrays and array sizes. I was very surprised to find that method 1 tends to be the best.

[image]

The blue, orange, and green lines correspond to methods 1, 2, and 3 respectively. The style of the line indicates how many arrays were multiplied together.

The results are surprisingly consistent. Even when you have 8 arrays, it seems faster to just use `a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h`. I'm not entirely sure why this is. Perhaps Python sees this expression and does a divide-and-conquer combination style, whereas reduce is completely linear?

Code for the benchmark is here:

https://github.com/Erotemic/misc/blob/main/tests/python/bench_np_reduce_vs_repeat.py